# Is there a realtime train position and timetabling tool for Deutsche Bahn trains?

Tags: trains, western-europe, deutsche-bahn

In the UK, there are several third-party services which consume data produced by Network Rail regarding the operational rail timetable and live train movements. These services produce data which are highly informative regarding my journey. For example, I often use such services to determine where a train originates, from which inbound service it was formed (if applicable), and to ascertain the timeliness of the service when en route. I am a particular fan of [Real Time Trains](http://www.realtimetrains.co.uk).

Are there any equivalent services for Deutsche Bahn trains? I'm aware of the [beta DB Live Map](http://www.apps-bahn.de/bin/livemap/query-livemap.exe/dn?L=vs_livefahrplan&livemap=yes), but am looking for a service which provides textual timetable information regarding train formation and intermediate passing points, rather than a graphical readout.

My current motivation is to search for the train I am shortly due to board in Brussels; the online timetable indicates it is delayed, and I wish to determine whether the train originates here and, if so, from which inbound service it forms, so I can determine whether it is likely to be in the platform already.

It would be particularly great if there was a service worked across borders into other Western European countries where DB long-distance services operate, but I can understand this is perhaps unlikely due to the cross-border data sharing required between the various network operators.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There is https://reiseauskunft.bahn.de/bin/bhftafel.exe , where you can enter the station your train originates from (along with date and time or the train number) and see all the trains departing with platform and delay. You can click on the train number and then you get to see the entire trip of the train including all intermediate stops.

If you're already on your way, use m.bahn.de . "Departure/arrival" allows to search by station or you can use "Is my train on time" if you know the train number. Or simply use the journey planner, it uses real time data, too.

Unfortunately, if the train originates from the station, the website won't tell you from which incoming train it forms, you can only guess (e.g. if it's an ICE bound for Frankfurt, chances are high that you should look for an inbound train from Frankfurt).

Looking at the departures from Brussels, it seems like all trains are shown, not only those running to/from Germany, but I have too limited knowledge to tell if the listing is complete or how far from Germany data is available.